# Measure data transfer throughput?

Tags: debian, http, bandwidth, latency, metrics

How can I benchmark the network transfer speed of my servers? We already have an existing file server, but it is fairly old. We recently got a donation of a (relatively) newer P4 box, and I wanted to find a way to test its network+disk I/O speeds to determine if the speed benefit is worth the work to set up a new server.

We're using Debian Lenny as our OS, and all our clients are connecting via HTTP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanted to just have a look on the bandwidth actually used, give `nload` a shot.

I always prefer testing the daemon which is serving clients (wget/curl when testing a webserver, lftp for ftp-servers, etc). Artificial tests like `iperf` are better to check the general throughput of your routers, switches, NICs and IP stacks.

HTH,
PEra

Answer (score 2):

iperf

Here ya go:

http://www.go2linux.org/how-to-measure-your-network-bandwidth-and-performance-with-iperf

Answer (score 2):

WGET will show transfer rates. Stick a large temporary file up on the server (say, dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=1M count=200) and bring it down w/ HTTP. Watch out if you're doing any kind of compression in your HTTP server-- I believe new WGET builds can do gzip encoding.

Edit:

One could argue that you should probably create a script w/ wget to poll a group of URLs that are similiar in composition as to what a "typical" visitor to the site would be accessing, as well. What I describe above is raw brute-force network / IO bandwidth testing (albeit influenced by disk caching, no doubt). Testing a potentially randomly-generated set of requests w/ wget would be another good test case, too. You could have a lot of fun with this one... >smile<

Comment: +1, for practical and quick method. Have used this myself couple of times. But, would this be good for taking a go-no-go decision for a server?

Comment: That depends on your "go no-go" criteria. If the criteria is only throughput then yes. If you're talking about behaviour of application software being hosted by the machine then I'd say you need a more rigorous test suite. I've done test suites for web-based applications that involve polling various URLs with wget and parsing the results to see if the application responded properly. So, certainly, wget *can* be used for more advanced testing, but here the poster was asking only about throughput.

Answer (score 2):

iperf. Or if you want to go old-school, ttcp.

http://www.carumba.com/src/ttcp.c

Answer (score 2):

iperf for network bandwidth testing, bonnie++ and/or iozone for disk testing. All of them can be found in the debian repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and quick solution:

```
wget http://myserver/large.file.avi
```

At the end wget command will print the throughput.

Answer (score 1):

I found this paper http://www.nik.no/2009/06-Hansen.pdf provides very good comparison of online and standalone bandwidth test tools. It includes Abget, Pathload, Netperf and Iperf.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with netperf for looking into network traffic performance issues.  I found this [debian link](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=netperf) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Give [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home) a go.

> Siege is an http regression testing
>   and benchmarking utility.